# NSURL download file, indicators shows too late

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I got the following code and want do show an ActivityIndicator while downloading. But the indicator shows only when the download has finished?

```
_fanDownloadIndicator.hidden = NO;
NSLog(@"batzn");
NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fan_new.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:file];

if(fileExists == NO) {

    NSURL *downurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downurl];
    if ([data writeToFile:file atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"downloaded fan");
```

Comment: is there more code? right now I don't see where you show the indicator

Comment: @connor The 1st line of code shows the indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You are doing the download task on main thread, and you wait until the thread ends before you show your loading view.

## Solution

You need to start downloading task on background thread by using dispatch_async. Check out the code below

```
_fanDownloadIndicator.hidden = NO;
NSLog(@"batzn");
NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fan_new.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:file];

if(fileExists == NO) {

//Show your loading view here

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

            //Do your downloading here on background thread
            NSURL *downurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downurl];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([data writeToFile:file atomically:YES]) {
                    //Hide your loading view
                    NSLog(@"downloaded fan");
                }   
            });
        });
}
```

Also I'll provide a suggestion for your loading view which is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). Here is what you can do with it

```
//Show loading form here
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

## Update

If you are dealing with downloading images, i should recommend this library:

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

It also offers a third party to show activity indicator.

Comment: Thanks I found the MBProgressHUD already but I think that isn't the right way in my app to show that something is downloading. I have Imagesviews when you click one them the download starts so if you want to download 2 images at once the HUD is maybe not the right for me